# Using $.xml2Json return a complicated object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-plugins, xml-parsing

I have this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: trgUrl,
    success: function (data)
    {
        var xml= $.parseXML(data);
                               {
        var obj= $.xml2json(xml);

        //....
    }
 });
```

and `data` can be somthing like:

```
 "<name> Mike </name>"
```

now, the problem is that after using `$.xml2json(xml)`,  in order to show the name i need to write:

```
 alert(obj.name.value); // Mike
```

instead of just:

```
 alert(obj.name);    // object object
```

in other words: the `$.xml2json` turns the content of `<name>` into another object (instead of making it a direct string)

**How can i fix that behavior?** does anybody had this problem ?

Comment: Try setting the `dataType` to `'xml'` in the ajax call and skip the `$.parseXml` part. Pass the data object directly. I've used xml2json myself and didn't have this problem.

Comment: I tried that , but got the same results.  did you used xml2json()  or $.xml2json()  ?

Comment: Pretty sure it was `$.xml2json`, but i cant check until tomorrow when i get back to work..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rB4Dy/ This is the version that im using, please try it out.

Comment: Johan, thanks. from some reason, when i am using it, it returns undefined. but i found somthing else: x2js.xml2json convertor, and it seems to work fine, so i will stick with it. thanks for all of your time and efforts. cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify plugin as follows:

```
// Add element value
if(node.childElementCount == 0 && node.textContent != null && node.textContent != "") {
         /* comment out ".value" */
         result[node.nodeName]/*.value */= node.textContent.trim();
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ycN37/

If nodes have child nodes this can create problems which is likely why author created object in first place

Comment: but is your solution solve this broblem (in regard to your last sentence)?

Comment: depends on what your xml looks like. Did you try it? Why is it so difficult to use `value` property in object?

Comment: my xml is  far more complicated than the simple example i used ,  and i already wrote functions to handle the converted object, except that it isn't acting as i was hoping it would. anyway, what you find consist with my issues (i wasn't imagining that, nor did i do somthing wrong in my ajax-code,  and that is a start...).